# R: read.csv adding sub-script "X" in header

Tags: r, header

I have a data frame that has headers as this

```
Name  0x1  1x2
```

read.csv changes the header to be

```
Name X0x1 X1x2
```

Is there a way, where this can be avoided?

Thanks.

Comment: Read `?read.csv`, where it describes the `check.names` argument.

Comment: And be warned that there are good reasons that `read.table` and friends sanitize the names.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

according to @Joshua

```
read.csv("filename.csv",check.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: someone please tell me why that worked. I've spend 2 hours on this and 20 stack overflow postings. This is insane.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my Mac. There was a X... at the beginning of the first variable. The problem was that the CSV file was actually a CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) file. Saving the file as a CSV (Comma separated values) solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `quote=""` option will also prepend an `X.` for each column of your `data.frame`. If you can, try to remove that from your `read.csv` options, else add the `check.names=F` option which will override that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. The solution for me on MAC machine is to save the file with fileEncoding = "macintosh". Then read it by doing check.names = F.

Answer (score 0):

```
read_csv('file_name.csv",check,names=F)
```

check.names=F, strips the white space character and removes the "x"

Comment: looks like `check,code=F` here