# Append a different character other than 'X' to make sytactically valid column names

Tags: r, csv, read.table

When reading a csv, R automatically appends the letter X to syntactically invalid column names. For example:

```
> read.csv(text = "a,1,b")
[1] a  X1 b
```

How, can I append a different letter within the read.csv function when reading in the file, for example instead of 'X' appending 'foo' to give the output?:

```
[1] a  foo1 b
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548199/r-read-csv-adding-sub-script-x-in-header

Comment: I m not sure there is an argument in `read.csv` that lets you change that prefix.

Comment: It seems to depend on `make.names()`, according to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/x-in-my-column-names-of-an-r-data-frame). `?make.names` does not show any way to change the default, though.

Comment: Also related - [Check if character value is a valid R object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396577/check-if-character-value-is-a-valid-r-object-name)